# Oracle SQL Developer - load Excel file into sql server

Tags: sqldeveloper

I am trying to import Excel data into a table in SQL Developer.

I have created table in SQL Developer. Then I use Data Import Wizard to import the Excel file into the table.

The problem comes when dealing with date/time information. See picture Data Import Wizard 2, I just can't seem to get the correct date/time format correct.

I think the format string should be DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM. But this doesn't work. My other attempts failed too.

Would appreciate any advice on this. Thank you.

P.S. I am learning from the following youtube video. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gR47cdxZibA

Raw data:
[image: Raw data]

Table properties:
[image: Table properties]

Data Import Wizard:
[image: Data Import Wizard]

Data Import Wizard 2:
[image: Data Import Wizard 2]

Comment: And the format field is not an input field where you can put dd/mm/yyyy HH12:mi ?

Comment: So what should I do? Am I supposed to modify my data in Excel to fit the default formats?

Comment: I would assume you use this to tell sql developer in what format the date you are importing is formatted in.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do that. But it is not working for me. Any idea how I should do it?